# Slow indexing in Aurora PostgreSQL (Serverless v2)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to build an index for a table with 1B of rows. 24 hours has passed and the query is still running:
`CREATE INDEX idx1_table1b on table1b using HASH(column1)`.

Since *column1* is often filtered with equality operator(=), I've chosen hash indexing to be the index type. The DB instance class I'm using is Serverless V2, ACU min-max:16-128, PostgreSQL 14.6.

Not sure if I missed anything in the configuration or statement, any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You can check the create progress of the index with [pg_stat_progress_create_index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING)

Comment: Just because you mostly test for equality doesn't mean you should use a hash index.  Btree indexes are generally superior (for implementation reasons, not theoretical reasons).  Only if the values in column1 are very long (many hundreds of bytes) would I consider using the hash index.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, I used btree now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the column has tons of **duplicate value**, which might be the cause why the hashing halted(or took a long time to build hash-index).

The solution to my problem is to use btree(which accommodates well duplicate values) and the indexed was built in minutes. The performance of using indexed column to perform join in a query is at milli-second performance.